# Taking input in Sublime Text 3

Tags: c++, sublimetext

I have problem in sublime text 3 in input taking. I write code in C++ but when I compile it does not support for any input from user. What should i do for this? is there any console package?

Comment: Don't know about sublime 3. But Visual Studio Code has a terminal window where you could compile and run the code. Anyway, the IDE is meant for development, and the input taking it's a runtime task, usually done in the console/terminal. Just open a console/terminal, use the VSCode terminal, or look further for the Sublime 3 terminal extension (if it exists)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot input in the same results panel you have compiled in with Sublime.
However, you can configure Sublime for running the compiled program in an external terminal.

The link below gives you steps on how to do this:

**Click Me: [Guide to compile Sublime in external terminal](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminal)**